# Changing text appearance in Emacs: overlays work, text properties don't

Tags: emacs, overlays

I've been experimenting today with text properties in Emacs.  If I position the cursor on a line with some text on it and then execute the following code with `M-:`, the line is redisplayed in bold.

```
(overlay-put
 (make-overlay
  (line-beginning-position)
  (line-end-position))
 'face 'bold)
```

If, however, I wipe out the overlay with `(remove-overlays)` and execute the following code, nothing happens (except that the word "nil" appears in the minibuffer).

```
(put-text-property
 (line-beginning-position)
 (line-end-position)
 'face 'bold)
```

From what I've gleaned so far, I'd expect that these two snippets should produce the same visual results.  Why don't they?

Comment: Works for me with Emacs 23.1, with text in a buffer in both fundamental-mode and text-mode.

Comment: 22.1.50 isn't an official build, I'd try grabbing an official release from http://homepage.mac.com/zenitani/emacs-e.html

Comment: I downloaded and installed the official release, and the same problem occurred.  But I chanced upon the answer regardless.  I opened a new empty buffer and typed some random gibberish, and setting text properties worked there.  The buffer I tried all my experiments in originally was in xml-mode (or sgml-mode, whatever).  So at least I can apply text properties now, but it's still a mystery to me how (and why) certain modes can countermand put-text-property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `font-lock-mode` is on, the `face` attribute will be overridden.  Try `font-lock-face` instead:

```
(put-text-property
 (line-beginning-position)
 (line-end-position)
 'font-lock-face 'bold)
```

Answer (score 2):

ansi-color.el -- "In Emacs, however, things are a bit
different: When font-lock is active in a buffer, you cannot simply add
face text-properties to the buffer.  Font-lock will remove the face
text-property using 'font-lock-unfontify-region-function'.  If you want
to insert the strings returned by 'ansi-color-apply' into such buffers,
you must set 'font-lock-unfontify-region-function' to
`ansi-color-unfontify-region'.  This function will not remove all face
text-properties unconditionally.  It will keep the face text-properties
if the property 'ansi-color' is set.